# Transparent Image Button not Loading

Tags: android, xml, image, png, imagebutton

I have 10 image button where 35% area of this images are totally transparent. After publishing this app I getting crush in Note 2 & Galaxy S5. Then after testing on that devices a noticed that when I remove that images background as this images then it works otherwise not.

Then what can i do now?

Its very essential for me to keep then transparent.

App crush from setContentView:
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

XML Parts of ImageButton:

```
     <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewImageType"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonType0"
                    android:layout_width="184dp"
                    android:layout_height="198dp"
                    android:layout_margin="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/robindronath_thakur" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonType1"
                    android:layout_width="184dp"
                    android:layout_height="198dp"
                    android:layout_margin="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/kaji_nazrul_islam" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonType2"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="195dp"
                    android:layout_margin="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/jibonanondo_das" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonType3"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="195dp"
                    android:layout_margin="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/sukanto_vottacarjo" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonType4"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="195dp"
                    android:layout_margin="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/sukumar_ray" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonType5"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="195dp"
                    android:layout_margin="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/josim_huddin" />


                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonType6"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="195dp"
                    android:layout_margin="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ahosan_habib" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonType7"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="195dp"
                    android:layout_margin="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/sotendronath_datto" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonType8"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="195dp"
                    android:layout_margin="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/forrukh_ahmed" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ImageButtonType9"
                    android:layout_width="180dp"
                    android:layout_height="195dp"
                    android:layout_margin="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/issorcandro_gupto" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: seems you are using some latest function to set Image Background. use generic one. if this doesn't solve your problem then post your logcat or line of code for more details.

Comment: Actually I dont have logcat Now. It's "memory out" error. I can provide logcat 5h after. And its stop from:

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

That means its problem of XML.
Then I remove image button from xml. Then its work. So its problem in Button.I am putting code in question.